# How can I change the crashlytics apikey inserted into my AndroidManifest.xml by the crashlytics eclipse plugin

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, crashlytics

I am moving an app between organizations and running into a problem where the crashlytics plugin for eclipse (using kepler) won't finish its onboarding process to the new account.

I've read through their [support page](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/130381-how-do-i-transfer-my-app-to-another-organization-) on how to accomplish that but cannot finish the onboarding process to the new account because the plugin interface seems to only work with the old api key, and therefore I can't get it past the WAIT status after I launch my app because the api key is wrong for the new account.

[image]

What I've observed is that each time I tried to start the onboarding flow with the plugin it inserts the old api key into my manifest.

Stuff I've tried:

1. revert all code changes from first crashlytics integration
   AND
   uninstall the crashlytics eclipse plugin and reinstall it, then go through onboarding flow again by logging in to the new account (I logged via safari to add the new app, I am not asked to login via the plugin again which is really strange).
2. try to manually change the crashlytics api key in android manifest. This doesn't work because the plugin will make its own changes to the android manifest and insert the old api key again.
3. manually change the api key again and just run that version without restarting the onboarding flow in the plugin.

The app has been removed from the old crashlytics account already.

How can I change the api key that the plugin is working with?

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but if you open the popup and hit Ctrl-L, it will log you out. Perhaps logging back in will fix the issue? EDIT: Nevermind, I see you already re-installed and logged in.

Comment: @kcoppock thanks for your tip on Ctrl-L, that actually worked! I am surprised that an uninstall/reinstall wouldn't work but this did. I verified it is inserting the right api key now. I clarified the steps I tried to note that I had logged in to the web interface, not the plugin to start the onboarding flow again. Strange it did not ask me to login to the plugin again after a reinstall.

If you make that into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glad to hear it worked! You can fix this by logging out through the plugin. Open the plugin window and press Ctrl+L to log out.